# docker container nginx start but keeps hanging

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

my dockerfile:

```
FROM AWS_ECR_IMAGE

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        cron \
        python-dev \
        git \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        autotools-dev \
        automake \
        libbz2-dev \
        libaio-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        python-pip
RUN pip install boto boto3 awscli

# Install Nginx.
RUN \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y nginx && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /etc/nginx

# Define default command.
CMD ["nginx"]

COPY nginx_conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# Start service, replace server name, update web ui
COPY main.sh /opt/annotation-pipeline-docs/main.sh
RUN chmod 0755 /opt/annotation-pipeline-docs/main.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "/opt/annotation-pipeline-docs/main.sh" ]

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 80
```

And my entrypoint bash file (I need to update the server name first when the container runs) is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync s3://${S3_Bucket}/docs/${ENVIRONMENT}/HEAD/ /var/www/html/

if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" == "prod" ]
then
  sed -i.bak "s/REPLACE_ME/example.com/g" /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
else
  sed -i.bak "s/REPLACE_ME/example-$ENVIRONMENT.com/g" /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
fi

nginx 

while true; do
  sleep 60
  echo "s3 sync again:"
  /usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync s3://${S3_Bucket}/docs/${ENVIRONMENT}/HEAD/ /var/www/html/
done
```

The issue is when

```
nginx
```

runs, it will hanging forever in the terminal:
[image]

and the while loop will never get called. Anyone know why is hanging and how to resolve it? Please help, tks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe you would like to enable the debug log and inspect it.

Comment: I'd expect it's not "hanging", it's serving traffic.  In the same way that, for example, the `echo` in the final loop doesn't run until the `sleep 60` completes, the final loop won't run until the `nginx` command finishes.

Comment: More practically, I would run this sync job outside the container.  Injecting _data_ into a container using a bind mount is a reasonable way to use a server container like this.

Comment: I agree with David Maze. Adding to that, there are many solutions to this problem. Different wording of the root problem; the issue is `nginx` is running in the foreground and will never release the focus to rest of your script to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for my issue is waiting for the traffic, the while loop will never get called until Nginx start free the bash. However, Nginx will be running in the foreground and not release the focus.

The solution I tried is instead of letting Nginx running as a foreground service, I changed it run in the background. Since this is the only service in my container, should have no problem to do it.

the code changed is simply removed below line in my dockerfile:

```
echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

which will make Nginx as a foreground service